# permuting digits of a number

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Given a number $N$ with upto 18 digits, We need to find how many numbers smaller than $N$ can be formed using the same digits.

Eg:
 for 725

we can form 527,572,257,275 hence answer=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to have a nice formula, but you can formulate a recursive algorithm to compute it.  The basic idea is that the numbers of length $n$ are all those formed from:
a) a smaller digit of $N$ that the lead digit and any permutation of the rest
b) the same lead digit as $N$ and a permutation of the rest that is smaller than the number formed after removing the first digit of $N$

a) yields to the calculation of permutations, accounting for the multiplicity of each digit.  You have to decide whether a leading zero is permitted.  It clearly is after the first step
b) is a recursive call, with a number one digit shorter.